# Domain based filtering for outbound traffic

Tags: firewall

I am using Linux as a router in my environment. I have to restrict outgoing traffic to only certain domains on certain port and block the rest.

IP based filtering is also not feasible because some of the domains which we connect are using dynamic IP's and it keeps changing.

Is there a way to filter outbound traffic based on DNS name?

Answer (score 1):

Generally this cannot be done with a firewall. (chicken and egg). The firewall needs to protect the DNS along with everything else; so firewalls (and I can only speak directly to `ipfw` and `pf`) simply do not make DNS queries. i.e.: at boot time, the firewall is up LONG before mundane systems like BIND; so name-dependent rules simply fail to load.

Maybe you want to consider a proxy? e.g. squid et al.

OpenDNS also provides an interesting solution (they filter DNS queries if you configure them as name server).